# Catchable fatal error on 3.6 update

Tags: php, wp-error

Trying to debug the situation. Getting close, but will need a little help!!

Here is the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/Alexia/lib/functions/common.php on line 97
```

And my code from the error:

```
// no cache files - let's finally resize it
        $new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
line 97-->      $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );
        $new_img = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $new_img_path ), $image_src[0] );
        // resized output
        $vt_image = array (
            'url' => $new_img,
            'width' => $new_img_size[0],
            'height' => $new_img_size[1]
        );

        return $vt_image;
    }

    // default output - without resizing
```

Thanks in advance NINJAS!!

Comment: The function [image_resize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize) has been deprecated in favor of [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor)

Comment: ps: image_resize returns WP_Error on failure so you are most likely trying to feed getimagesize() with the WP_Error object instead of a string input value as expected. Do some error checks before using it.

Comment: @birgire please post answers as **answers**, rather than as **comments**.

Comment: @ChipBennett, thanks :  my comment didn't start out as an answer but after few thoughts and edits, it became a "comment-answer", and 1 minute later, very similar answer was posted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`image_resize` (deprecated)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize) is returning an error object so really, the problem is here: `$new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );` Something is wrong with that line and you are not checking whether the return value is an error object or a string before trying to use the return value as a *string*.

You did not post any code that might help me work out what is wrong with `$new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );` but at the very least you should do:

```
$new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
if( !is_wp_error()) {
    $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );
    // ...
```

Converting to use [`WP_Image_Editor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) would be wiser though.

Comment: ok, so I can convert it using wp_image_editor ?

Comment: Yess, you can and _should_ convert to `WP_Image_Editor` Deprecated functions will eventually go away.

Comment: Any chance someone could help converting ?

Comment: I can probably work it out later